# BooleanProperty whose value depends on if a node is added to a Scene

Tags: java, javafx, nullpointerexception, boolean, scene

I'm working on a slide menu for JavaFX, and in the definition of it I constantly make use of the `getScene()` method for referencing the height and width of the scene to which the node is added.

The problem is that the slide menu is defined before the scene does, returning a `NullPointerException`.

I think that a workaround for this would be creating a `BooleanProperty` with a listener that each time that the value of the property changes, would check if it's `true` or `false`, executing the lines of code that involve a call to the `getScene()` method or not, respectively.

How could I achieve this? I thought that I could do this by saying

```
BooleanProperty hasScene = new SimpleBooleanProperty();
hasScene.set(getScene());
hasScene.set(Boolean.valueOf(getScene()));
hasScene.set((boolean) getScene());
```

but it's not possible to cast from `Scene` to `Boolean`.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
hasScene.bind(sceneProperty().isNotNull());
```